JS Object Standard Prototype as a Symbols
Looks like it is not really feasible or very tricky still I'll take a try.
Say we have a config data of a fluent structure for user to provide.
E.g.
configRoot:
  fluentSubSection:
     someProp: 12
     valueOf: John Doe
     toString: whatever
     toJSON:
        implementation: 'some-npm-one'
        indentation: 2

How to make

The user possible to provide really any data without any restrictions on property names
Same time to be able to customize the functionality of ConfigNode representation class with some standard handlers such as toString, valueOf, toJSON

Whether it possible it achieve the same functionality on some Symbol/Proxy/Other-Hucky way. So that To split the functional and data level representation. Still to leave the natural data access through the pure properties way (without any accessors e.g. node.readProperty('propertyName')
E.g.
const config = loadConfig('...')
console.log(config.configRoot.fluentSubSection.valueOf) 
// John Doe
// plain content data access outputs the value provided by user

console.log(config.configRoot.fluentSubSection.toString) 
// whatever 
// plain content data access outputs the value provided by user

Still the ConfigNode instance it self should have some custom functionality under the hood (without harm for plain acccess to a user provided data properties) as
// Customize in some hucky way the functionality
ConfigNode[#toString_Symbol] = () => `[Custom ConfigNode - ${
  Object.entries(this)
    .map(
      [key,  value] => `${key}: ${value}`
    ).join(';')
}]`
ConfigNode[#toJSON_Symbol] = () => JSON.stringify(
    {...this}, 
    null, 
    this.toJSON?.indentation // the value from a data access level
)

console.log(String(config.configRoot.fluentSubSection)) 
// Should switch to some functional level access for toString implementation 
// E.g. [Custom ConfigNode - someProp: 12; valueOf: John Doe; toString: whatever]

JSON.parse(config.configRoot.fluentSubSection)
// Should switch to custom JSON marshaling implementation


So how to customize toJSON, toString, valueOf, etc. related functionality of ConfigNode class and still to be able to provide same data properties as a plain regular values.
P.S. maybe someone grasp the idea and can see how to express the issue in more clear way please help as well :)
Anyway please any ideas are appreciated.
Thx

It is how to keep both js functionality and pure data set representation. YAML doesn't really matter just for an ease of structure view.

JSON.parse just provides a data part. Another side is to customize functionality of nodes like toString etc. Covered in topic.

Yes exactly. That is actually the point. toString as a content data is ought to be able provided as a regular data type for the config value. Still related js based functional should be still customizable the same time. Updated the post a little with more clear explanation.

@ElliottFrisch Added with more detailed examples

Basically you want to overload properties to return different type values based on the getter's call context.
A short answer: SORRY that's not C++ with type cast operator overloading.
This pattern is basically absent in JS and I strongly don't recommend it.
You could try to overload though some way like this:


'use strict';

class Sub{
  #bucket = {};
  constructor(props){
    Object.assign(this, props);
  }
  get toString(){
    const out = () => {
      return Object.prototype.toString.call(this);
    }
    out.toString = () => this.#bucket.toString;
    return out;
  }
  set toString(val){
    this.#bucket.toString = val;
  }

}

const configRoot = {
  fluentSubSection: new Sub({
     toString: '[John Doe]',
     userProp:true
     })
};

console.log(configRoot.fluentSubSection);
console.log(String(configRoot.fluentSubSection.toString));
console.log(String(configRoot.fluentSubSection));




Yes. I agree that my intention could be expressed not that clear at the initial post. I've tried to explain it more clearly. Please check the updated question.

Thanks for the solution. Bu it looks just generalize access to toString as a property. Yet it was about to diverge access to a data property toString as a config value and the customized implementation of logic javascript relies of that property as a method. Same for valueOf and toJSON.

@404 i doubt that justifies overloading properties C++ way...

Oh, agree on some objective huckery stuff. Still the key point here is not really to override  but more to separate data model it self and behavioral functionality.

Actually for now I've found a partial solution with Symbol.toPrimitive which solves the issue for toString and valueOf.
Actually it allows achieve the same just on step earlier and without populating the data properties scope with method functions.
class ConfigNode {
[props: string]: any;

[Symbol.toPrimitive]() {
    return `[Custom ConfigNode Representation]`
}

}

const node = new ConfigNode()
node.toString = 'whaterver'

console.log(`${node}`) // [Custom ConfigNode Representation]
console.log(node.toString) // whaterver

The cons is that primitive would be the. same both for String and value representation. Still it works for my case.
Still for toJSON this doesn't seem to work. So I keep on researching.
